Parallel processing, but process objects with the same identifier sequentially
I am using an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I would like to process objects with the same identifier sequentially, whilst in parallel to different identifiers.
To illustrate the issue, given my object is as follows:
class Data 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string o { get; set; }
}

So with a list as follows:
var l = new List<Data>() 
            {
                new Data() { Id = 1, o = "xxxxxx" },
                new Data() { Id = 1, o = "yyyyyy" },
                new Data() { Id = 12, o = "aaaaaaa" },
                new Data() { Id = 12, o = "ccccccc" },
                new Data() { Id = 97, o = "mmmmmmm" }
            }

I would expect 3 "queues" in parallel. One processing Id=1, another Id=12 and another Id=97.
I have been using Channel<Data> to
foreach(var x in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))

the data to process in a BackgroundService. But this leads to one long queue, which then processes everything sequentially.
I am looking for pointers on how I might go about implementing such a requirement. Parallel.ForEach came to mind - where it would group those with the same Id and put them in the same thread, but I am not sure if this grouping functionality is available yet.

You didn't post any code that creates 3 queues, only a single Channel, which acts as a single asynchronous queue.  Use Parallel.ForEachAsync to process the IAsyncEnumerable<Data> returned by ReadAllAsync in parallel, using all available cores. You can restrict the number of concurrent workers using the MaxDegreeOfParallelism option

Related: Dynamically processing a concurrent collection in parallel by group but serially within each group.

I tested out the solution you provided in the related question by @TheodorZoulias and it was exactly what I needed.

You can group elements of your list using the method GroupBy in this way:
myList.GroupBy(d => d.Id)

you can then use Parallel.ForEach to perform parallel processing of the grouped list
Parallel.ForEach(myListGroupedById, elementsById => {})

In this example, elementsById is an IEnumerable containing all elements of myList of the same id
Using these informations on your sample code would result in something like this:
var myList = new List<Data>() 
{
   new Data() { Id = 1, o = "xxxxxx" },
   new Data() { Id = 1, o = "yyyyyy" },
   new Data() { Id = 12, o = "aaaaaaa" },
   new Data() { Id = 12, o = "ccccccc" },
   new Data() { Id = 97, o = "mmmmmmm" }
};
    
var myListGroupedById = myList.GroupBy(d => d.Id);
    
Parallel.ForEach(myListGroupedById, dataBySameId => {           
    foreach (var data in dataBySameId) {
        // sequential work here
    }
});


As a side note, I highly recommend to specify the MaxDegreeOfParallelism whenever you use any of the Parallel APIs.

Whilst this solution works, it does not take into account that the data's source is a Channel. If that were not the case, your solution would have been perfect. I ended up using @TheodorZoulias solution that he linked to in the comments
